# jsf listener not called inside nested ui:repeat

Tags: ajax, jsf, listener

I have a problem using `ui:repeat` nested in each other where I'd like to call a listener. I have also tried `c:forEach` instead, but got the same problem.

For demonstrating the problem I have simplified the code to the problem.
There are two buttons, the first inside the first ui:repeat, calling successful a simple listener. The second button is inside the nested ui:repeat element, should call the same listener as the first button, but the listener is never called.

Can you please tell me whats wrong with this?

```
<div>
    <ui:repeat var="testList" value="#{testBean.testList}">
        <h:commandButton value="test1">
            // the listener is called if I click this button
            <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" listener="#{testBean.testListener}" />
        </h:commandButton>
        <ui:repeat var="nestedList" value="#{testList.nestedList}">
            <h:commandButton value="test2">
                // the listener will not be called if I click this button
                <f:ajax event="click" execute="@this" listener="#{testBean.testListener}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </ui:repeat>
    </ui:repeat>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your `h:form` ? also remove `event="click" execute="@this"` from buttons

Comment: There is a surrounding `h:form`, I have just simplified the code here.
I dont' use buttons in the actual code, just to test for myself and for demonstrating here. Even if I remove both attributes the listener is not be called by the second button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known Mojarra issue related to broken state management of `<ui:repeat>`. Specifically this issue is reported as [issue 1817](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1817) and fixed since Mojarra 2.1.15.

Upgrade your Mojarra version. It's [currently](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) already at 2.1.19.

Comment: Thank you very much.
This solved the problem.

But unfortunately I get an NullPointerException after calling the listener in javax.servlet.http.Cookie.setDomain with Mojarra 2.1.17 and 2.1.19. The previous version (2.1.16) works fine!

Comment: As per your edited comment, ask a new question with the complete stacktrace or report it to Mojarra guys if you're confident that it's a Mojarra bug.