# JSF2 & <ui:repeat> <ui:repeat> <h:commandLink> <f:param <f:ajax>

Tags: jsf-2

I have a problem with jsf2 & combination of `<ui:repeat>`  `<ui:repeat>` `<h:commandLink>` `<f:param>` `<f:ajax>` tags

if i use one `ui:repeat` tag then i get my call on ajax listener method
but not if there is a nested `ui:repeat` tag.

Thank you

i have a @PostConstruct to 
private LiferayDocument liferayFolderAktuell;
private List liferayFoldersArchiv;

this one WORKS - it sends an event to backingbeans method addToInfomappex

```
 <ui:repeat var="file" value="#{documentService.getFiles()}" >

<h:form id="frm_#{file.documentId}">

    <h:commandLink id="a_#{file.documentId}" class="addToInfo" data-tooltip="Zur Infomappe" alt="Zur Infomappe hinzufügen" >

        <f:param value="#{file.documentId}"  />

        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{documentService.addToInfomappex}" />

        link                        
    </h:commandLink>

</h:form>

</ui:repeat>
```

This one does not work - the are 2 ui:repeat tags - i get no event to the same method:

```
<ui:repeat var="folder" value="#{documentService.liferayFoldersArchiv}">
    #{folder.title}             

    <ui:repeat var="file" value="#{documentService.getFiles(folder.documentId)}">

    #{file.title}       

    <h:form id="frm_#{file.documentId}">

    <h:commandLink id="a_#{file.documentId}" class="addToInfo" data-tooltip="Zur Infomappe" alt="Zur Infomappe hinzufügen" >

        <f:param value="#{file.documentId}"  />

        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{documentService.addToInfomappex}" />  
        link                            
    </h:commandLink>
    </h:form>   
    </ui:repeat>
  </ui:repeat>
```

Comment: There are issues when nesting `ui-repeat`, try using a `c:forEach` as an outer loop.

Comment: sorry but i don't want to mix jslt & jsf - there are a lot of problems with that mix.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14975758/1530938

Comment: don't work cause i use jbossas7 & they have  2.1.7 version. and: you can not overwrite it - great java world - after 12 years of java programming i can't solve smallest problems. it is so frustrating, you have to use tonns of frameworks & each framework make java poorer.