# nested jsf listener not called in @ViewScope

Tags: ajax, jsf, listener

Currently I have a problem similar to
[jsf listener not called inside nested ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975758/jsf-listener-not-called-inside-nested-uirepeat)
After I got the solution of this problem I upgraded Mojarra to Version 2.1.16.
Everthing works fine, up to the moment I was implementing the below-mentioned view.

The Code is simplified to the basics.

xhtml:

```
<form>
  <div>
    // listener is called
    <h:commandLink value="test1">
      <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{testBean.testListener}" />
    </h:commandLink>
    <ui:repeat var="testList" value="#{testBean.testList}">
      // listener is not called !
      <h:commandLink value="test2">
        <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{testBean.testListener}" />
      </h:commandLink>          
    </ui:repeat>
  </div>
</form>
```

bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="testBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {
  private Collection<TestObj> testList;
  public Collection<TestObj> getTestList() {
    return this.testList;
  }

  // the listener
  public void testListener() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Even if I change `ui:repeat` to `c:forEach`, the problem is the same!
Just if I use `@SessionScope` instead of `@ViewScope` the 2nd commandLink (inside the iteration) calls the listener. But I'd like to avoid `@SessionScope` at this bean.
Do you have any hints for me about the reason of this problem and how to handle it?

Comment: Can you put breakpoint on `@PostConstruct` method and see if it is called after click on link inside `ui:repeat`? Just to check if bean is recreated on AJAX request.

Comment: Yes, the bean is recreated on both ajax requests.
So the reinitialized collection contains other objects than listed with `ui:repeat`. This means jsf is not able to find the objects of the collection in the dom-tree, so the nested the listener is not called!?
But shouldn't `c:forEach` avoid this problem?

Comment: Can you post code for whole page?