# How to use <ui:repeat> to iterate over a nested list?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, nested-lists, uirepeat

Using JSF 2.0, I need to display a table wherein each row contains a link which opens a popup. I have two models: `A` which has `id` and `List<B>` properties and `B` which has `id` and `name` properties. In my backing bean, I have a `List<A>` property. In my view, I am using `<ui:repeat>` to iterate over `List<A>`.

The requirement is, depending on the row that the user clicks, the corresponding `List<B>` of `A` needs to be displayed. However, the `<ui:repeat>` does not accept a nested list to be assigned in the `var` attribute. Hence, I need to do a lot of workarounds which is not efficient.

How do I efficiently solve this problem?

Comment: Show us what you've tried!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What you need is to nest another `<ui:repeat>` tag in your outer iteration:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.listOfA}" var="a">
    ...
    <ui:repeat value="#{a.listOfB}" var="b">
        ...
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

The only thing left that is worth noting is that nested `<ui:repeat>` tags used to have problems with state management until Mojarra 2.1.15 version (details in [jsf listener not called inside nested ui:repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975758/jsf-listener-not-called-inside-nested-uirepeat/14979480#14979480) and in many not so recent questions and their answers), which could result in action listeners not called, etc. but if you're currently on the latest Mojarra JSF implementation - just skip this part altogether.