# Dynamic datatable for columns and rows jsf (JSF2)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-1.2

I actually followed below link added columns and row data as dynamic, little confused on how to show on xhtml. any help

http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html#PopulateDynamicDatatable

```
List<String> strlist = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<List<String>> dynamicListynamicList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        strlist.add("Name");
        strlist.add("SSN");
         for(String columnName : columnNamesList){
             strlist.add(columnName);
    }

         List<String> rowData = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(String otherList : listData){
             try {
                 rowData.add(otherList.getName());
                 rowData.add(otherList.getId());
                    if(otherList.getAmount() != null){
                         for(BigDecimal amount : otherList.getAmount()){
                             if(amount != null){
                                 rowData.add(amount.toString());
                             }else{
                                 rowData.add("");
                             }
                         }
                    }else{
                        for(String s : strlist){
                             rowData.add("");
                        }
                    }

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 dynamicListynamicList.add(Arrays.asList(rowData.toArray(new String[rowData.size()] )));
            }

        String[] strarray = new String[strlist.size()];
        dynamicHeaders =   strlist.toArray(strarray );
        populateDynamicDataTable(dynamicListynamicList);

        private void populateDynamicDataTable(List<List<String>> dynamicList2){
             HtmlDataTable dynamicDataTable = new HtmlDataTable();
             for (int i = 0; i < dynamicList2.get(0).size(); i++) {
                 HtmlColumn column = new HtmlColumn();
                 dynamicDataTable.getChildren().add(column);
                 HtmlOutputText header = new HtmlOutputText();
                    header.setValue(createValueExpression("#{dynamicItemColumn[" + dynamicHeaders[i] + "]}", String.class));
                    column.setHeader(header);
                    HtmlOutputText output = new HtmlOutputText();
                    output.setValueExpression("value",
                        createValueExpression("#{dynamicItem[" + i + "]}", String.class));
                    column.getChildren().add(output);
             }

             dynamicDataTableGroup = new HtmlPanelGroup();
             dynamicDataTableGroup.getChildren().add(dynamicDataTable);
             setDynamicList(dynamicList2);
```

every thing works fine as data being added, now i wasnt sure and my apologies, how to iterate in jsf page(xhtml), to show relvant columna nd rowdata..

Comment: Please clarify if you're using JSF 2 or JSF 1.2 since you can have different solutions on each. Also, note that this BalusC post dates from 2006, more than 7 years ago.

Comment: Am using JSF2 and was not able to go after other third party due to requiments.

Comment: Since you're using JSF 2, you can nest `<ui:repeat>` as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15726600/1065197

Comment: sorry may be i mis confused, how the h:datatable would? i mean          <h:dataTable value="#{bean.dynamicList}" var="dataItem">
            <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="???" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="???" />
              
            </h:column>

Comment: No need to use `<h:dataTable>` since you can use `<ui:repeat>` to build the `<table>` HTML instead.