# creating multiple Ul in ui:repeat manually

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cmsBean.cmsVo.attributesList}" var="attribute">

<ul>
    <li>
       <div>"#{attribute.name}"</div>

    </li>
</ul>

</ui>
```

Now I have to create separate lists from attributeList , <ul> based on value of #{attribute.attributeType}  , how can I use do it.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do the same thing as you have done before, but now using the new attribute as the "name" property of the ui:repeat.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cmsBean.cmsVo.attributesList}" var="attribute">
    <ui:repeat value="#{attribute.newList}" var="newList">
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

A similar question along with a sample code can be found here:
[How to use <ui:repeat> to iterate over a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726600/how-to-use-uirepeat-to-iterate-over-a-nested-list)

Simply do the same thing as you have done before, but now using the new attribute as the "name" property of the ui:repeat.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cmsBean.cmsVo.attributesList}" var="attribute">
    <ui:repeat value="#{attribute.newList}" var="newList">
    </ui:repeat>
</ui:repeat>
```

A similar question along with a sample code can be found here:
[How to use <ui:repeat> to iterate over a nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726600/how-to-use-uirepeat-to-iterate-over-a-nested-list)

If you want to create a new html unordered list:

1. Inside the same ui:repeat: simply begin it again, and you will have a nested unordered list.

   - item1
     - item2
2. Outside the ui:repeat: you should save the list with the values in another variable inside the managed bean in order to access it (through a getter) as the property value of the second ui:repeat.

Comment: hi @andriosr, thanks for answer. but I don't have multiple list , I have to create multiple multiple <ul> based on a field of var attribute , and attribute is a java list

Comment: I updated the answer, check if it is what you are looking for.