# JSF - How to implement header and details table recursively in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

[Header and Details recursive tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzXns.png)

I have requirement to implement table structure like in picture (header table followed by details table). We have an employee class and his/her certification details are modeled by another class.

I have list of these 2 classes available to be iterated over. How do i implement desired table structure. Will it be one datatable within the other or UI repeat would help.

Comment: Or simply use a nested `ui:repeat` that creates table rows and cells: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726600/how-to-use-uirepeat-to-iterate-over-a-nested-list

Comment: @Kukeltje: you mean by using native HTML table, TR, td tags? Isn't there something in JSF which could help

Comment: @BalusC: Any advise please

Comment: `ui:repeat` IS jsf. Otherwise see the answer

Comment: @Kukeltje: I apologies if i wasn't clear earlier. What i meant was - isn't there a way in JSF to get control of defining rows in data table other than creating table using native HTML tags. For my  situation, if i use data table within data table, i won't get desired result. It will first show all rows on Employee and then all rows of certification. What i want is to show certification details per employee and not for all of them together.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use third party libaries? I would recommend you dataTable from primefaces.
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml

Comment: I can use richfaces